# Marching Cubes not forming any unified mesh

Tags: javascript, babylonjs, marching-cubes

I started using Babylonjs a few days ago and, as I noticed it was very simple to use and powerful, I decided to try and make marching cubes algorithm.

I can’t quite understand why it isn’t working. I’ve changed the code so that I can manipulate the vertices values, draw a single cube and the output was the expected. However when given random values it doesn’t show any meaningful mesh.

This is hard and I appreciate anyone who may be able to help me, thanks in advance!

I'm sorry for [the code](https://playground.babylonjs.com/#0J3CGA#1) being that big but I can't narrow it down as I have no clue to why it isn't working.

Comment: How is there such a gap between having the confidence to undertake something as complex as a marching cubes mesh generation algorithm and "I have no clue to why it isn't working".  Surely you must have some idea as to what you were expecting as a result.  Have you tested any parts of it at all?  How do you (we) know there isn't just a typo somewhere?

Comment: So, i was solving this all day long and i think i figured it out. It is tricky to explain but i'll do my best. The algorithm was/is working just fine, the problem are the values of the vertex's were completely random (on purpose) thus not generating anything meaningful. I've gone ahead and somewhat included perlin noise instead of random values. I haven't finished it yet but i'm making progress as seen  [here](https://i.gyazo.com/86d7903e43626b728658838533921d56.png)